# Copying Shortcuts to Desktop

Tags: c#, .net, copy, desktop, shortcut

I have this small tool I'm working on to help manage menus for another application.  I need this tool to copy shortcut files like it would any other file.  Unfortunately, it'll copy every file but files with a .lnk extension.  Does anyone know why?  I can't seem to find anything on this.  I'm not creating shortcuts from scratch, I'm copying existing ones.  I've tried both the FileInfo.CopyTo() and File.Copy() methods.  It actually copies the file, then throws the exception which is really weird.  If I wrap it with a try..catch.. (with nothing in the catch) then it seems to work with the exception that some of them lose their shortcut icons.  Not that it might help much, but here's the gist of my code:

```
DirectoryInfo destinationDirectory= new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop));    
string temppath = Path.Combine(destinationDirectory.FullName, sourceFile.Name);
sourceFile.CopyTo(temppath.FullName, true);
```

**Answer:**

Thank you Alireza for pointint me in the right direction.  Here's what I ended up doing:

```
DirectoryInfo destinationDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop));
FileInfo shortcut = sourceFile.Directory.GetFiles("*.lnk").FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == sourceFile.Name) as FileInfo;
if (shortcut != null)
{
  File.Copy(shortcut.FullName, Path.Combine(destinationDirectory.FullName, shortcut.Name), true);
}
```

Comment: Try this and report the result: var shortcuts = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)).GetFiles("*.lnk");

Comment: That returns a FileInfo[] with two items (for two shortcuts on my desktop).  Each shows to have the lnk extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var shortcuts = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop))
               .GetF‌​iles("*.lnk");
string destFolder = destinationDirectory.FullName;
foreach(var f in shortcuts)
    File.Copy(f.FullName, Path.Combine(destFolder,f.Name));
```

Comment: Well, that works going from the desktop to another folder, but trying to go from a master folder to the desktop I get an access denied exception.  I probably should've mentioned that too.  I get this exception, yet like I said it still copies.  It's very odd which made me question my method.

Comment: Okay, I did a variant of what you were saying to do and got it to work.  I still don't understand why.  It seems I can't simply take the path associated to the file and go from there.  I evidently have to read the file?  Does this have to do with the file attributes?  I'll append my result to my question for clarity for others.